# Google Sheet VLOOKUP REGEX

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with

IP Address  DNS Name    MAC Address Port    Switch  VLAN
    AP-2802I-16

and another Sheet within the same workbook with
vlan    mac     type    switch
216    Yes Switch Name

I'm trying to build a VLOOKUP with REGEX to take the mac address in the first sheet, look it up in the second sheet and only display the corrosponding switch, port, and VLAN if the port starts with gi or te, case insensitive.
I have `=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(IF(len(C2:C),vlookup(C2:C,{Port!B2:C},2,FALSE),"")),"")` but I can't get a regex or wildcard to work in there. Any help would be appreciated.

Tried =IFERROR(ArrayFormula(IF(len(C2:C),vlookup(C2:C,{Port!B2:C},2,FALSE),"")),"") and can't get a regex in it.

*Edit*
I have this Sheet. In the first tab, I have the IP Address, DNS name, and Mac Address of the device. I have VLAN, Mac Address, port, and switch name in the second tab. I need to grab the Mac Address from the first tab and search for it in the second tab, but only return the information from the line if the port is Gi or te and ignore the other lines with the Mac Address.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bIAKbQn8ylpHFHOjTdiRJ6mU8uIkhkGLRSRvHvuoBqU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm sorry, honestly I have no idea about the differences between those two ways of expressing information and how they correlate. Could you share an example of the value to lookup and how is the data shown in table in where to look?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(C2:C),IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C,FILTER({Port!B:D,Port!A:A},REGEXMATCH(Port!C:C,"(?i)^gi|te")),{2,3,4},)),))
```